# Import a bunch of parameters as a dictionary?

Tags: python

I want to put all the parameters of my code in a parameter file (parms.py), so that everything I may need to tweak later will be at the same place. What would be the best way to import just the parameters I want, to save some work?

I was thinking of grouping my parameters in dictionaries; is that the Pythonic way? I think the code will look funny, using the parameters like: `parms_dict('parameter1')`

```
from parms.py import * # import lots of useless parameters (should I worry about that?)
```

or

```
from parms.py import parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4, parameter5, parameter6, parameter7 # That way can get very long and ugly (should I worry about that?)
```

Any better suggestions/comments?

Comment: `import parms; print parms.parameter1`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just import the module and access the parameters you want using their fully-qualiifed names:

```
import parms

parms.foo
parms.bar
parms.baz
```

Comment: Aside from using the fully-qualified name, isn't it equivalent to "from parms.py import *" I mean performance wise it still import all the parameter?

Comment: "performance wise it still import all the parameter" Yes.  It always imports the entire file.  There's no other way.

Comment: `from xxxx import *` is generally a bad idea because you can't look at a variable in the code and figure out where it came from. (`from xxxx import x1, x2, x3` is better because you can see where `x1` came from.) However, from a performance standpoint, all imports are nearly identical. The whole module is always imported (unless it has already been imported, in which case it doesn't need to be). The differences come in what's imported from the module to the current namespace: a reference to the module as a single name, or a reference to one or more individual names from inside the module.